# Find a vector $z$ so that system of linear equations $A^{T} \cdot y=d$ is solvable if and only if $d^{T} \cdot z=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Find a vector  $z$ so that system of linear equations $A^{T} \cdot y=d$ has solution if and only if $d^{T} \cdot z=0 \\$ Matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & -3 &4 \\
    1 & -2 & 1&-4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

I tried to create augmented matrix with $A^{T}$ because of $A^{T} \cdot y=d\space$ (maybe this is wrong ?) $$[A^{T}|d]= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&1&d_1\\
  0&1&-2&d_2\\
-1&-3&1&d_3\\
1&4&-4&d_4\\
\end{array}
\right]$$ for some $d=(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4 \in \Bbb{R})$ $$-$$

Ref of this augmented matrix is $$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&1&d_1\\
  0&1&-2&d_2\\
0&0&-1&d_4-d_1-2d_2\\
0&0&0&d_1+d_2+d_3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$ For sure $d_1+d_2+d_3=0$, because system has to be solvable, and $d_1=-d_2-d_3$ $$-$$
Can I now do multicipation $\space d^{T} \cdot z=0 \\$ like $$\begin{bmatrix}
    -d_2-d_3 & d_2 & d_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1  \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}=0 \\$$ $$-$$ So, my solution will be,
$$ x_1=(1/d_3)\cdot x_2 + (1/d_2)\cdot x_3 \\[1ex] \Rightarrow z= \begin{bmatrix}
    (1/d_3)\cdot x_2 + (1/d_2)\cdot x_3  \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\$$
If this is correct, can someone help me to solve this but in another dirrection..

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
A^Ty=d \ \ \text {is solvable}\Longleftrightarrow d\in\mathcal R(A^T) \stackrel{\text{assumption}} {\color{blue}{\Longleftrightarrow}} d\perp z
$$ where $\mathcal R(T)$ denotes the range of $T$ and $\mathcal N(T)$ the null space. Thus $\mathcal R(A^T) =\langle z \rangle^\perp$ and this implies that
$$
\mathcal N(A) =\mathcal R(A^T)^\perp = \langle z \rangle.
$$ We find that $Ax=0$ is solved by $$
x=c \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\\0  \end{array} \right).
$$ Therefore $z$ can be any vector of the form $c(1,1,1,0)^T$ where $c\ne 0$.

Comment: You mean $A^{T}y=d$ is solvable $\Leftrightarrow d \in \mathcal{R} (A^{T}) \\ $
Why $Ax=0$,I mean why homogeneous system ?

Comment: @Figgaro Since $d\in \mathcal R(A^T)$ is equivalent to $d\perp z$, we have $\mathcal R(A^T) = \langle z\rangle^\perp$. Hence $\mathcal N(A) \color{red}= \mathcal R(A^T)^\perp = \langle z\rangle^{\perp \! \perp} = \langle z \rangle$. This gives $z$ is a basis of $\mathcal N(A)$, so it naturally leads to solving $Ax =0$.